# Firebase Sign in with custom token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase user set up:

[image]

Then, based on the [following](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), I get a custom token from the `uid` (`MG76cXdqhDNrx3BJktUq62...`) on the server.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String customToken) {
            // Send token back to client
        }
    });
```

Then, on the client, it returns the custom token. I then `signInWithCustomToken` as you can see below.

```
getUserWithToken(personModel: PersonModel): Promise<firebase.User> {
    return new Promise<firebase.User>((resolve) => {
        this.firebaseService.getCustomToken(personModel.uid).then((customToken: string) => {
            this.fireAuth.signInWithCustomToken(customToken).then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
                this.fireAuth.onAuthStateChanged((fireUser: firebase.User) => {
                    if (fireUser && fireUser.uid === personModel.uid) {
                        resolve(fireUser);
                    } else {
                        resolve(null);
                    }
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error getting user with CustomeToken login for ' + personModel.uid, error);
                this.doAlert(error.message);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

But, instead of signing in the with above (with the `uid` `MG76cXdqhDNrx3BJktUq62...`) user as expected, Firebase creates a new user with a different `uid` `RoPBW0NKRoWEI1o8wgb9DD...`:

[image]

It's as if it getting the `uid` of an old user and creating that user. However, I would expect it to just sign in with the user associated with the passed `uid` `MG76cXdqhDNrx3BJktUq62...`.

Any advise appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION

The issue was a silly mistake on my part.

The server code was caching an old custom token, because it was being saved on the class instance.  Fixed by removing the custom token on each time the method is called.